Issue creating database for a HTML Form using PHP
I am creating my CV website and am creating a contact me form at the bottom of my website. So I am using HTML, CSS, PHP and Java to help me with this. Basically, I want to create a database in myPHP within Hostinger as my server to view and download people's entries. I am having trouble getting the HTML to communicate with PHP to make it work properly.
I've tried using formsubmit but it times out so frequently so I am opting to learn PHP and use this as a learning tool. My issue is I get a HTTP 405 or 500 error after I hit the submit button. Can someone help me with my PHP code please? I will post both HTML and PHP. The HTML code is in a file called form.html and the PHP code is inside the file dbnew.php. Thanks in advance
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="dbnew.php" method="POST">
        <div class="input-box">
            <div class="input-field">
                <label for="fullName">
                <input type="text" name="fullName" placeholder="Full Name" required>
                <span class="focus"></span>
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="input-field">
                <label for="email">
                <input name="email" type="email" id="email" pattern="/^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/" placeholder="Email Address" required>
                <span class="focus"></span>
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
            <div class="input-box">
                <div class="input-field">
                    <label for="phone">
                    <input type="tel" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="Phone Number" required>
                    <span class="focus"></span>
                    </label>
                </div>
            
                <div class="input-field">
                <label for="emailSubject">
                <input type="text" name="emailSubject" placeholder="Email Subject" required>
                <span class="focus"></span>
                </label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="textarea-field">
                <textarea name="emailMessage" id="" cols="30" rows="10" name="message" placeholder="Your Message" required></textarea>
                <span class="focus"></span>
                
            </div>

            <div class="btn-box btns">
                <button type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
            </div>
            
    </form>
</body>
</html>

<?php
 $fullName = $_POST['fullName'];
 $email = $_POST['email'];
 $phone = $_POST['phone'];
 $emailSubject = $_POST['emailSubject'];
 $emailMessage = $_POST['emailMessage'];

 if (!empty($fullName) || !empty($email) || !empty($phone) || !empty($emailSubject) || !empty($emailMessage)){
    $servername = "https://mywebsite.com";
    $database = "u292472425_mywebsite";
    $username = "u42424823_username";
    $password = "MyPassword#1234";


 
    // Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);
if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
        
            die('Connection error('. mysqli_connect_errno().')'. mysqli_connect_error());
        
        }else{
            $SELECT = "SELECT email From register Where email = ? Limit = 1";
            $INSERT = "INSERT Into register (fullName, email, phone, emailSubject, emailMessage) values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
    
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($SELECT);
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $email);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($email);
        $stmt->store_result();
        $rnum = $stmt->num_rows;

        if ($rnum==0) {
            $stmt->close();

            $stmt = $conn->prepare($INSERT);
            $stmt->bind_param("ssiss", $fullName, $email, $phone, $emailSubject, $emailMessage);
            $stmt->execute();
            echo "New record inserted successfully";
        } else {
            echo "Someone already registered using this email";
        }
        $stmt->close();
        $conn->close();

        }
    } else{
        echo "All fields are required";
        die();
    }
?>


I also want to point out that I am trying to use Hostinger as my server since it will be running 24/7 vs my localhost server on my laptop.

Is the code you posted in dbnew.php? If not, what's in that file?

Do you see any errors in your log file and/or errors on Inspect Element? Is the phone field being submitted a string or integer? The database is expecting an integer so double check that is the case.

yes, the php code is in the file dbnew.php. and it says its a net error or mainframe error when I inspect the code

Give us the exact error you receive, not an abbreviated or rephrased version.

I get:  HTTP ERROR 405  == $0

Thanks. Not sure how that counts as a a net error or mainframe error?! HTTP 405 means "method not allowed", which means the webserver you're running this on won't accept the HTTP method which was used to send the request. This often happens when testing locally if you use some basic webserver (e.g. the one included with Visual Studio Code is a common example) instead a proper one which has full HTTP support and PHP integration. Or running HTML files from the filesystem (so it uses file:// instead of http:// protocol) instead of via the webserver is another common mistake.

I appreciate you trying to help @ADyson I think this is way over my head. Very new to databases and PHP.

Well the issue is nothing to do with your database certainly - it's not getting that far.

How are you testing your code, exactly, when you get this error? Where are you running it?

e.g. If you're testing locally in your own machine I'd expect that you'd have installed Apache  and PHP (perhaps via XAMPP to make it easy!) and would then be accessing the HTML form by going to something like http://localhost/form.html in your web browser. That should ensure it's running via the Apache server, so that when you submnit the form, Apache can accept the resulting HTTP POST request from the browser, and use PHP to execute the code in dbnew.php, and return the result. If you're getting a 405 error when submitting the form then it sounds like something along the way isn't set up
